# Read file, pick field values and make it tab delimited

Tags: shell

I have a file like:

```
Book: English  
Book: Latin  
Fruit: Orange  
Fruit: Apple  
Fruit: Grapes
```

I need to pick up only the values and make them `|` delimited for similar fields, followed by `\t` and then `|` delimited with the second field values and so on.

For example, the output should be:

```
English|Latin   <\t>   Orange|Apple|Grapes
```

I tried with the code below but, I didn't get exactly what I wanted.

```
$ file=file1.txt
$ while read line; do
      if [[ $line =~ Book: ]]; then
          echo "${line##*: }" | tr '\n' '|';
      fi ;
  done < "$file";
  echo -e '\t';
  while read line; do
      if [[ $line =~ Fruit: ]]; then
          echo "${line##*: }" | tr '\n' '|';
      fi ;
  done < "$file";
  echo -e '\t'
```

Please let me know where I am going wrong. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Using awk

Try this:

```
$ awk -F': ' '{a[$1]=a[$1](length(a[$1])?"|":"")$2} END{printf "%s\t%s\n",a["Book"],a["Fruit"]}' file1.txt 
English|Latin   Orange|Apple|Grapes
```

**How it works**

- `-F': '`

  This tells awk to use colon-space as the field delimiter.
- `a[$1]=a[$1](length(a[$1])?"|":"")$2`

  For each line that we read from the file, this tells awk to append the second field to array `a` under the key specified by the first field.  If the array value at the start is not empty, then it appends `|` before adding the second field.

  The strange-looking part, `(length(a[$1])?"|":"")`, is a *ternary statement*.  If `length(a[$1])` evaluates to true (not zero), then the ternary expression returns the string `"|"`.  Otherwise, it returns the empty string, `""`.  The effect of this is to add `|` between words but *not* before the first word.
- `END{printf "%s\t%s\n",a["Book"],a["Fruit"]}`

  After we have finished reading the file, this tells awk to print the list of Books followed by a tab, `\t`, followed by the list of Fruits, followed by a newline, `\n`.

### Using shell

```
a=
b=
while read key value
do
    case "$key" in
        'Book:') a="$a|$value";;
        "Fruit:") b="$b|$value";;
    esac
done <file1.txt
printf "%s\t%s\n" "${a#|}" "${b#|}"
```

This produces the output:

```
English|Latin   Orange|Apple|Grapes
```

Comment: Brilliant..!! thanks John.. it worked.. If you can and only if you have time, can you please explain a little more about a[$1]=a[$1](a[$1]?"|":"")$2

Comment: @Sanjivi Glad it worked for you.  I added discussion of the ternary statement to the answer.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, John!

Comment: Hi John, I need to update a little to the script.
The awk command finds the pattern only if it starts at the beginning of the line. For example if the line starts with some words like the below:
"Some words here Book: English"
This doesn't return. I tried using reg ex but it was not giving the results. Can you please help me?